# How to convert the log4j.properties file to log4j2.xml or log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have updated the logging jars from log4j1 to log4j2.11. However I am not able to convert my log4j.properties file into log4j2.xml file or log4j2..properties file. Below is my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,DG
log4j.logger.com.datag=INFO
log4j.appender.DG=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DG.Append = true
log4j.appender.DG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz} | %5p |[%t] |%C:%M(%L) | %m %n
log4j.appender.DG.File=/home/Tracer.log
log4j.appender.DG.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.DG.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/home/Tracer.log
log4j.appender.DG.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/home/Tracer.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
log4j.mr.log.filePath.enabled=N
log4j.mr.log.filePath=/home
```

How can I convert this file into log4j2.properties and xml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Configuration status="ERROR">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="DG" fileName="/home/Tracer.log" filePattern="/home/Tracer.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz" append="true">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %5p |[%t] |%C:%M(%L) | %m %n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.datag" level="INFO"/>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="DG"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the .xml file. When I have used this file and started the project I faced an issue in the error logs file ".NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of property PatternLayout must not be null at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]"

Comment: I have modified the configuration above to add the status attribute. If you change it to debug it should provide detailed output about creating the logging configuration. I didn't test the above configuration so it is possible I made and error of some kind.

Comment: Okay I will try that..one thing more,  I want to add two more properties in log4j2.xml shared by you...    log4j.mr.log.filePath.enable=Y and    log4j.mr.log.filePath=/tmp

Comment: How are these properties used by the configuration?

Comment: Actually when the value of first property is yes then map reduce logs gets created on the path that is mentioned in the second property.

Comment: How?  I see nothing in the log4j 1 configuration that would do that.